# I already integrate HUAWEI Location Kit successfully. But now got error permission denied

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Recently the Location Kit stop working and throw 10102: PERMISSION_DENIED exception.

I already have location permission for app AND HMS Core. Sim card is use as well.
Location Kit version: 4.0.4.300

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. I got the same problem and it is very unexpected and frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

The error code 10102 PERMISSION_DENIED is caused by insufficient permission, see [Location Kit-Result Codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/error-code-0000001050992067-V5) (huawei.com). Please verify that the location permission has been assigned to HMS Core (APK).

The following is the FAQ provided detailed instruction answer for the error code solution:

What should I do if the API is called successfully but the device location cannot be obtained?

Ensure that you have installed HMS Core (APK) 3.0.0.300 or later.

Ensure that the location permission has been assigned to HMS Core (APK). To do so, go to Settings > Apps > Apps and find HMS Core. (The menu path may vary depending on the operating system version. If HMS Core is not found, tap the menu icon in the upper right corner of Apps and tap Show system processes.) Then, tap the HMS Core (APK) icon, go to App info > Permissions > Location, and verify that the location permission is assigned to HMS Core. On a device running EMUI 10.0 or later, Location must be set to Always for HMS Core.

Ensure that Location is enabled for the app to be tested.

Ensure that Location is enabled on the notification panel.

Verify that the GPS or network signal is strong. In regions where the GPS or network signal is weak, the location may not be obtained.

Verify that a SIM card is inserted into the device and works properly so that Location Kit can provide more precise locations.

Comment: For some reason the  HMS Core app does not have system level permission. Need to manually active location permission. Very confusing

Comment: Giving HMS Core permission to location fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing the HMS core data and try again.